# Python, calculating number of days between two dates return wrong value in one specific case

Tags: python

I wrote a program to calculate the number of days between two dates and it works fine except for one case. If I want to calculate the number of days between two dates and the end date is in February the number of days is not correct (exactly three days are missing)

Example:

```
Date 1: 2012,1,1
Date 2: 2012,2,28
Program returns 55 days (should be 58)
```

I guess there is an issue with the leap days but I don't get why this does not cause any wrong values for any other two dates and why the difference between the correct value and the value of my program is 3 days. My code example which should work as is can be found below. Any advice is appreciated.

```
daysOfMonths = [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

# Count the number of leap years

def countLeapYears(year, month):
    if month  <= 2:
        year = year - 1

    return int(year/4 - year/100 + year/400 )

# Determine the number of days between 0/00/0000 and the two dates and calculate the difference

def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    days = 0
    n1 = year1 * 365 + day1
    for month in range (0, month1):
        n1 += daysOfMonths[month]
    n1 += countLeapYears(year1, month1)

    n2 = year2 * 365 + day2
    for month in range (0, month2):
        n2 += daysOfMonths[month]
    n2 += countLeapYears(year2, month2)
    return n2 - n1

def test():
    test_cases = [((2012,1,1,2012,2,28), 58),
              ((2011,6,30,2012,6,30), 366),
              ((2011,1,1,2012,8,8), 585 ),
              ((1900,1,1,1999,12,31), 36523)]
    for (args, answer) in test_cases:
        result = daysBetweenDates(*args)
        if result != answer:
            print "Test with data:", args, "failed"
        else:
            print "Test case passed!"

test()
```

Comment: Why don't you use `datetime`?

Comment: Just trying to implement it without a built-in function..

Comment: In your example shouldn't it be more than 365 days because the years differ by `1`?

Comment: Sorry about that...that was a typo..but the issue is the same anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an off-by-one error in these lines:

```
for month in range (0, month1):
...
for month in range (0, month2):
```

Lists are zero-indexed in Python, but months are one-indexed in your program. So the proper code is:

```
for month in range (month1 - 1)
...
for month in range (month2 - 1)
```